# How to remotely access EC2 console using GUI

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, amazon-ec2

My local machine is Ubunut 18.04 My Amazon EC2 machine is also Ubuntu 18.04. I need to see GUI of my remote machine.

1) Is this possible? How (steps plz)?

Please note that SSH -X is not working with me. It is extremely slow to an extent that it is impossible. It is not working.

The support team suggested me using RDP. Can I use RDP from my local Ubunut 18.04? It also did not work. I doubt that RDP is for Windows machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to install an RDP client and connect that way. There are a few different ones listed [here](https://www.ubuntupit.com/10-fast-and-secure-remote-desktop-client-software-for-linux/)